# Div Overflow event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events, overflow

I am trying to trigger an event on div overflow and display the continued contents on to a new div, Is there any way this can be achieved, 
basically what I am trying to do is to display a document, page wise and every page is represented as a div and the div will have a particular height and width, so all I want to do is to display the hidden contents from the first div in a new div once that div has triggered a overflow event, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If one of the elements inside has a higher width or height than the parent then overflow will fire. Simply check for sizes

Comment: @Spokey I have edited my question, i have figured out the first part triggering an overflow event, now all i have to do is to get the hidden details from the div and display it in a new event.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) that adjust more to your needs to your `div` and handle it,

Or simple catch the event and do what you want:

```
$( "#yourDiv" ).click(function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

**EDIT** : check this links:

CHROME: http://help.dottoro.com/ljgsfkbc.php

FIREFOX: http://help.dottoro.com/ljgsfkbc.php

Comment: I have not idea what are you talking about!!! Really Sorry could you please explain, Thank you.

Comment: @Aoxi check new links in my edit, sorry, not much time, I hope it helps

Comment: Yes i have already read that, and it works with overflow: auto, my problem is different than that, i am trying remove all the hidden contents and add it to a new div and repeat the process until the content is filled in one div, but anyway thank you.